# Get average rate for the last one hour in Prometheus PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to get the average rate of request for the last one hour.

I am using the following query to get the rate

sum(rate(query_executes{*namespace*='oracle'}[1m]) by (database)

But if I were to get the average of the above rate for the last one hour, how do I do that?

Comment: Change "[1m]" to "[1h]" is not enough?

Comment: Does that give an **average** rate for the last one hour calculated over the period of 1m, does it?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Rates are fundamentally averages, if you would like to calculate "average(rate(some_metric[1m])[1h])" just execute "rate(some_metric[1h])".